# Css3 Transitions on android phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, css-animations

I wanted to make a android application with phonegap. After reading the article http://daneden.me/2011/12/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/ i new that css animations only work if you put every porperty in its own keyframe decleration. Now my navigation animation work out good but not the tabs transitions with the content.
Here you can see it: http://jsfiddle.net/XVqtm/

```
'<a> .tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
```

I appreciate every answer!

Nice greetings from Germany